# Getting Error while returning back using Server.Transfer()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have page (Default1.aspx) in which I am redirecting to another page (Default2.aspx) using `Server.Transfer()` method. After the page processing completed in Default2.aspx, execution  returns back to Default1.aspx, but at that time I'm getting the exception:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Why am I getting this and how can I avoid this when using the `Server.Transfer()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Server.Execute method instead. If it helps it might be that you are running into situation described at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. As you said i will try it, But i want to know the reason why am i getting the error. How does it comes.?

Comment: Assuming that Server.Execute fixes the problem, from explanation given in the above mentioned article, Server.Transfer calls Response.End and code after call to Server.Transfer is not executed. Server.Execute doesn't call Response.End and execution continues after Server.Execute.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable reply.